# In a list of lists, how can I find the mean of the values for each subindex?

Tags: python, list

I want to find the average of each index in a list of lists. Say I have this:

```
import statistics

my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11]]
```

I want to find the average of each interior list index, so:

- for index 0, I would have the value of (1 + 4 + 7 + 10)/4
- for index 1, I would have the value of (2 + 5 + 8 + 11)/4
- for index 2, I would have the value of (3 + 9)/2

and so on. How can I do this? Note that I do not need to save the values, just print them as they are computed.

Comment: You really have two questions: how to collect the values at each index from across the lists; and how to apply `statistics.mean` to each of those groups.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. I have edited your post to ask the question clearly and omit irrelevant discussion. (Also: please don't tell us that you spent hours searching for something; if you want to make the point, then show specific things that you typed into a search engine, explain what results you got that way, and explain why they did not solve the problem for you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer vanilla python, you can try the following:

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11]]

d = {}

for elem in my_list:
    for i in range(len(elem)):
        if i in d:
            d[i].append(elem[i])
        else:
            d[i] = [elem[i]]

for k,v in d.items():
    print(f'The average of idx {k} is {sum(v) / len(v)}')
```

Output:

```
The average of idx 0 is 5.5
The average of idx 1 is 6.5
The average of idx 2 is 6.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the package pandas to achieve your goal.

```
#import pandas
import pandas as pd
#you list
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11]]
#Create a DataFrame from your list
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
#mean for each row
df.mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `itertools.zip_longest`. You can group together by index, filter out any None elements returns by zip_longest, and then take the mean.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from statistics import mean

for i, group in enumerate(zip_longest(*my_list)):
    print(f'Index {i} mean:', mean(filter(lambda x: x is not None, group)))

# prints:
Index 0 mean: 5.5
Index 1 mean: 6.5
Index 2 mean: 6
```